# Input data for Keras LSTM

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I learn Keras LSTM – now try to understand data input shapes and preparation. For my example  - I want learn LSTM with 1000 sequences of int. The length of each sequence is 5. If the first element is 1 so Y is 1 and 0 otherwise
e.g. Input sequence -> 1 0 0 0 0, Output 1, 
     Input sequence 0 0 0 0 0 Output 0. Very simple for the beginning.

I prepare the data – 1000 samples, 5 timesteps, 1 feature

```
x_train = np.zeros((1000, 5, 1), dtype=np.int32)
x_train[0:500, 0, 0] = 1

x_test = np.zeros((300, 5, 1), dtype=np.int32)
x_test[0:150, 0, 0] = 1

y_train = np.zeros((1000, 1), dtype=np.int32)
y_train[0:500, 0] = 1

y_test = np.zeros((300, 1), dtype=np.int32)
y_test[0:150, 0] = 1
```

and created the model

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(10, input_shape=(5, 1), return_sequences=False, stateful=False))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=1000)
score, acc = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, batch_size=300, verbose=0)
```

and run

```
Epoch 1/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6790 - acc: 1.0000
Epoch 2/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6786 - acc: 1.0000
Epoch 3/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6782 - acc: 1.0000
Epoch 4/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6778 - acc: 1.0000
Epoch 5/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6774 - acc: 1.0000
Epoch 6/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6770 - acc: 1.0000
Epoch 7/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6766 - acc: 1.0000
Epoch 8/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6762 - acc: 1.0000
Epoch 9/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6757 - acc: 1.0000
Epoch 10/10
1000/1000 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6753 - acc: 1.0000
```

I have feelings I did something wrong with or X or Y data. Please look through the code and output – I tried to follow the documentation  - the input tensor shaped as [samples, time steps, features]

So I have 1000 samples, 5 timesteps, 1 feature – Right?

And the Y date is just 1000 samples and 1 fetture – so 1000x1 matrix.

Please advice if there is some misunderstanding in data preparation.

If the data ok I go further with stateful LSTM )